# Unable to start TaskTracker.Says Can not start task tracker because java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Does not contain a valid host:port authority:

Tags: hadoop, ubuntu-12.04

Edited mapred-site.xml,core-site.xml,hadoop-env.sh,hdfs-site.xml,masters and slaves.

I have 1 DataNode and 2 Namenodes.Both of them started successfully and I am able to see it in browser.
    Started start-mapred.sh and it started JobTracker and TaskTracker on the Namenode but unable to start Tasktracker on the datanaode.

Started Tasktracker and the following is the output.

```
->hadoop tasktracker
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

13/10/17 03:21:55 INFO mapred.TaskTracker: STARTUP_MSG:
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting TaskTracker
STARTUP_MSG:   host = tintin/10.193.184.157
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 1.1.2
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.1 -r 1440782; compiled by 'hortonf                                                      o' on Thu Jan 31 02:03:24 UTC 2013
************************************************************/
13/10/17 03:21:55 INFO impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
13/10/17 03:21:55 INFO impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source MetricsSystem,sub=Stats registered.
13/10/17 03:21:55 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
13/10/17 03:21:55 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: TaskTracker metrics system started
13/10/17 03:21:55 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
13/10/17 03:21:55 INFO impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source ugi registered.
13/10/17 03:21:55 WARN impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists!
13/10/17 03:21:55 ERROR mapred.TaskTracker: Can not start task tracker because java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Does no                                                      t contain a valid host:port authority:
10.193.184.132:54311   

at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.getAddress(JobTracker.java:2312)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.<init>(TaskTracker.java:1532)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.main(TaskTracker.java:3906)

13/10/17 03:21:55 INFO mapred.TaskTracker: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down TaskTracker at tintin/10.193.184.157
************************************************************/
```

Answer (score 1):

Though quite late to answer this, still does your mapred-site.xml contain mapred.job.tracker property ?

My job tracker runs on 8021, so the configuration is as follows:

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
<value>http://localhost:8021</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

I faced such an issue due to missing properties.